# Storing a list of entrants in a SQL table and adding a leaderboard

Tags: java, sql

I'm making a java web application for my golf society.

So far I've made all the user accounts and roles. I've made an events table in my database where a new event can be created. So far the event contains, id, name, course, date, cost and winner. Winner is null until the event has finished when a winner is entered.

I'm wanting to move on now and allow members to enter an event via the app and then a list of current entrants will be shown for each event. But I am stuck on how to go about this. I've thought about having a column in the DB for entrants, which will hold an array of people who have entered, but cannot find how to do it this way.

I have searched online for days and found nothing that helps.

Secondly once this is complete, the members who have entered would input their score for the round and this would create a leaderboard for each event.

I know this is possible as I use an app via my club which does the exact same thing, but I have spent days searching the internet but have come to a dead end.

Comment: Sorry, this is too broad of a question.

Comment: You will need a "*link*" table to implement *many-to-many* relationship between members and events. See https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-handle-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-datab or any other tutorial of your choice.